# How to increase display length in pg admin tool

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a dumb problem. Basically I just upgraded from pgsql 8.4 to 9.1 and upgrade to pgAdmin 1.20.

I have some tables that have large text fields and in the previous query tool I could query a row and copy-paste the data out of it to modify. In this case, I had a table that stored queries that I could run.

Once I upgraded to the new pgAdmin version, when I use the tool and query a row to pull out the text from a field in that row, it truncates the result and ends with an ellipsis (...).

I tried figuring out how to increase the mem on this so it doesn't truncate after 100 characters or so but couldn't.

Anybody have any ideas??

Comment: Unrelated, but: why upgrade to 9.1 _today_? Why didn't you go straight to 9.4? 9.1 will only be maintained for another year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pgAdmin options, you can change the length of the field. Do the following,
Go to:

> File > Options > Query Tool > Max. characters per column

By default it is 256, you can increase it accordingly.

 Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Marlon Abeykoon's answer is good, but if you want a one-off output and don't want to change settings, then simply output to a file (two buttons along from the usual green 'go' arrow).  This saves the entire output in a csv file.